# How to fix 405 method not allowed error while deploying my app on live server

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-405

I have an angular app with web api written in express and node.js.

In my angular app I am sending a http.put request to my webapi which is working perfectly fine in localhost.

But it is not working on live iis10 server and I am not the administrator. I have bought shared hosting. The error I am getting is **405 method not allowed error**.

After a long research I think that some module in iis10 is not allowing http verbs. After that I have done changes to my web.config file to solve the problem.

Following are the changes that I have done in web.config file. First I have removed the webdav module in my web.config file. But after removing the webdav module I still got the same 405 error. I tried to trouble shoot the problem with failed request tracing module in plesk, the description of the error is:

```
ModuleName      StaticFileModule
Notification    EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
HttpStatus      405
HttpReason      Method Not Allowed
HttpSubStatus   0
ErrorCode       Incorrect function.
```

I have also tried to fix the staticfilemodule error in web.config file but still got the same 405 error and still got the same error in failed request tracing.

Following is the web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>      
        <modules>
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />  <======== done changes      
        </modules>

                <handlers>
                <remove name="WebDAV" />    <========  done changes 
                <remove name="StaticFile" /> <========  done changes 
                <add name="StaticFile" path="*" <======== done changes 
                verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" 
       modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
                </handlers>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can any one please help me. I am stuck with this problem for many days